# Riddle on a fictional character 1

Tags: riddle, video-games

> I live in the coldest place,
>   but I don't freeze.
>   I always wear clothes,
>   but I don't need them.
>
> Betray my brother
>   and I disappear,
>   until the darkest (is it really?)
>   hour of your journey.
>
> I don't have a degree in law,
>   but I judge you.

***Who am I?***

---

Hint #1

> I come from a recent video game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> Sans, from Undertale (major game spoilers ahead)

I live in the coldest place, but I don't freeze.

> He lives in Snowdin

I always wear clothes, but I don't need them.

> A skeleton probably doesn't need clothes to keep warm, but maybe for decency.

Betray my brother and I disappear, until the darkest (is it really?) hour of your journey.

> If you murder Papyrus, Sans will leave you until you've killed everyone. Then...

I don't have a degree in law, but I judge you.

> At the end, he judges whether you've been good or bad (killing or not)

Comment: Hehe well done :)

Comment: I was "determined" to solve it.

Comment: My husband has recently started his Genocide Run and would greatly appreciate this collision of our two worlds. :)

Answer (score 2):

I got it!

> Sans, from the game Undertale.

I live in the coldest place,
but I don't freeze.

> He lives in a snowy area, but is a skeleton so cannot feel the cold.

I always wear clothes,
but I don't need them.

> Pretty much the same logic as above.

Betray my brother
and I disappear,
until the darkest (is it really?)
hour of your journey.

> Take the genocide path and slay Papyrus, and Sans disappears until the end of the game.

I don't have a degree in law,
but I judge you.

> Sans judges your actions at the end of the game and throughout. Take the genocide path and he fights you.

Edit: Gah, I got ninja'd.

Comment: Nice job regardless :)